# Reference to a dictionary value to reduce lookups

Tags: c++, dictionary

If I an have unordered_map `std::unordered_map<int, myClass> dic;` and I want to do a lot of assignments to a given element, would it be a good practice to use a reference to the object, so that I just search the dictionary once?. That is:

```
myClass& ref= dic[mykey];
ref.myval0=0;
ref.myval1=0;
ref.myval2=0;
ref.myval3=0;
```

instead of simply

```
dic[mykey].myval0=0;
dic[mykey].myval1=0;
dic[mykey].myval2=0;
dic[mykey].myval3=0;
```

Comment: Do both, compile with optimization enabled, and compare the generated assembly. [The compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org) is good for this.

Comment: that compiler explorer is cool!!!, thanks. But in any case, the idea is completely valid right?

Comment: It is perfectly fine, if you aware that `operator[]` may create new element if it was not there before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A better idiom would be to use iterators:

```
if (auto const it = dic.find(mykey); it != dic.end()) {
  it->second.myval1 = 0;
  it->second.myval1 = 1;
  // ...
}
```

This has the benefit that you add a check for whether the value actually exists.

In case you actually want to insert a new key-value pair, `unordered_map` has an [`insert`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/insert) member function just for that. It returns (among a boolean flag) an iterator that you can use just like `it` in the example given above.

Having said that, it should be pointed out that your approach is valid as well. It will have comparable complexity to these other two approaches. But it is at odds with the [RAII](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/raii) principle.